# Adding onclientclick events on rowdatabind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a grid view that is populated from a stored proc.

On the databind event I have added a onclientclick attribute as follows

```
deleteContact.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('Do you really want to delete)')"
```

This works fine but I now want to add a variable to the confim messgage so that it reads

"Do you really want to delete: CustID"

I have tried various iterations of;

```
deleteContact.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('Do you really want to delete)')" + variable
```

but none of them seem to work.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deleteContact.OnClientClick = 
    "javascript:return confirm('Do you really want to delete)')" + variable
```

Is not going to generate valid JavaScript.  In fact, that won't even compile because of the missing semicolon.  And the extra paren in the JavaScript won't be doing you any favors either.

This should work:

```
deleteContact.OnClientClick = 
    "javascript:return confirm('Do you really want to delete " + variable + "?');";
```